# How to state nontrivial tensor symmetry assumptions?

Tags: symbolic, assumptions, tensors

For example `dddg`, the third derivative of the metric tensor, in dimension $4$.

I need to state that it is symmetric in the first two indices and symmetric in the last three indices.

Comment: What do you mean by "state" here, and how will you be using the statement? I think how exactly you'll want to state it depends a lot on how you plan to use the statement!

Comment: I want to use it as an Assumption and TensorReduce an abstract tensor equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a small note in the documentation for `Arrays`,

> The symmetry sym can be given in several forms. First, it can be given as expressions like `Symmetric[{s_i, ..., s_k}]` or `Antisymmetric[{s_i,...,s_k}]`, with the slots `s_i` being different positive integers between `1` and the rank `r`. It can also be given as a list of generators of the form `{perm,\[Phi]}`, representing that the array stays invariant under simultaneous transposition by the permutation perm and multiplication by the root of unity `\[Phi]`. **In addition, it can be given as the internal direct product `{sym_1, sym_2, ...}` of those forms.**

So, we should simply be able to do

```
$Assumptions = {dddg ∈ Arrays[{4,4,4,4,4}, {Symmetric[{1, 2}], Symmetric[{3,4,5}]}
```

And indeed, `TensorTranspose[dddg, {2, 1, 4, 5, 3}] // TensorReduce`, for example, yields `dddg`.